# axios get request for localhost:3000/photos not returning anything?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, get, axios, expo

In my react native project i am trying to get data from a GET request using axios.

I know i need to change the 'localhost' in axios.get to the IP of my machine, even after doing this im not getting a response for my console.log statement.

axios code:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';
import PhotoSection from './photo-section';
//functional is just returning some data - static
//smart component for dynamic class component
export default class PhotoFeed extends Component {
  render() {
    axios.get('http://192.168.1.208:3000/photos')
    .then(response=>console.log(response));
      return (
      <View>
        <Text> hello </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: After the .then statement use a `.catch(err=>console.log(err));` that way you can see what the error is.

Answer (score 0):

Try hitting api from browser first

```
http://localhost:3000/photos // if this works follow below
```

Just put:

```
axios.get('/photos')
.then(response=>console.log(response));
  return (
  <View>
    <Text> hello </Text>
  </View>
);
```

Comment: I get a promise unhandled rejection with network error

Comment: whats the error. to get data are you running any back end in any of the different port ?